# XmlSerializer gera arquivo com espaço vazio antes da tag de fechamento

Tags: c#, xml-schema

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para gerar um xml:

```
public bool SerializarObjeto(object o, string pathArquivo)
{
    var xns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());

    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(pathArquivo);
    writer.Serialize(file, o, xns);
    file.Close();
    return true;
}
```

Gera o seguinte resultado em um determinado arquivo:

```
<item iis="078906590000500400348059" produzido="2016-07-15T07:34:54" />
```

Meu problema:

Preciso que não saia com o espaço vazio antes de fechar a tag:

Como sai: **`" />`**
Como deveria sair: **`"/>`**

obrigado.

Comment: A solução paliativa que adotei foi criar uma método para ler o arquivo e remover esses espaços. Acredito que essa forma de gerar o xml é do próprio XmlSerialize. Ainda procuro uma forma de resolver isso de uma forma mais correta..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, não conheço nenhuma opção nos objetos XML do .NET pra modificar esse comportamento, acredito que você vai precisar fazer um código nesse teu método pra fazer isso após a serialização, algo como:

```
var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathArquivo);
xml = xml.Replace(" />","/>");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathArquivo, xml);
```

Vale lembrar que se você faz alguma assinatura digital no XML, você tem que fazer esse replace ANTES de assinar, visto que vai alterar o conteúdo do arquivo

Comment: Obrigado @Pedro, foi exatamente essa a minha solução. Funcionou muito bem.